# Why does a space preceding a non-combining diacritic function differently when using IndexOf(string) and IndexOf(char)?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, substring, indexof

I am creating a substring from a string with non-combining diacritics that follow a space. When doing so, I check the string with `.Contains()` and then perform the substring. When I use a space `char` inside of an `.IndexOf()`, the program performs as expected, yet when using the string " ", within `.IndexOf()` the program throws an exception. As shown in the samples below only a `string` preceding the *primary stress* diacritic (U+02C8) throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Simple code (Edit suggested by John):

```
string a = "aɪ prɪˈzɛnt";
string b = "maɪ ˈprɛznt";

// A            
Console.WriteLine(a.IndexOf(" ")); // string index:  2
Console.WriteLine(a.IndexOf(' ')); // char index:    2

// B    
Console.WriteLine(b.IndexOf(" ")); // string index: -1
Console.WriteLine(b.IndexOf(' ')); // char index:    3
```

Sample code I tested with:

```
        const string iPresent = "aɪ prɪˈzɛnt",
                     myPresent = "maɪ ˈprɛznt";

        if(iPresent.Contains(' '))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iPresent.Substring(0, iPresent.IndexOf(' ')));
        }

        if(iPresent.Contains(" "[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iPresent.Substring(0, iPresent.IndexOf(" "[0])));
        }

        if(iPresent.Contains(" "))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iPresent.Substring(0, iPresent.IndexOf(" ")));
        }

        if(iPresent.Contains(string.Empty + ' '))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iPresent.Substring(0, iPresent.IndexOf(string.Empty + ' ')));
        }

        if (myPresent.Contains(' '))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myPresent.Substring(0, myPresent.IndexOf(' ')));
        }

        if (myPresent.Contains(" "[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myPresent.Substring(0, myPresent.IndexOf(" "[0])));
        }

        if (myPresent.Contains(string.Empty + ' '))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myPresent.Substring(0, myPresent.IndexOf(string.Empty + ' ')));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (myPresent.Contains(" "))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myPresent.Substring(0, myPresent.IndexOf(" ")));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not provide an example [like this](https://rextester.com/XDG17847)? It seems much simpler to digest than all of the code you've provided.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? I can't reproduce the problem as you describe it, and judging by the exception I'd say the problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: I guess I was too deep in the weeds think about showing just the index. I guess I was too wrapped up in the substring. I also wanted to show the different things I tested.

Comment: @Sach The only two lines within the `try` `catch`. Check the _Simple code_ edit that John suggested.

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but passing `StringComparison.Ordinal` to failing  `IndexOf`'s fixes it)

Comment: Just tried it on .NET Core, cannot reproduce, so not a culture thing, possibly a bug (?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`IndexOf(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) does something different from [`IndexOf(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_), because `IndexOf(char)`...

> ...performs an ordinal (culture-insensitive) search, where a character is considered equivalent to another character only if their Unicode scalar values are the same.

whereas `IndexOf(string)`...

> performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture.

So it's a whole lot "smarter" than `IndexOf(char)` because it takes into account the string comparison rules of the current culture. <s>This is why it doesn't find the space character.</s>

**After some testing in other languages and platforms, I suspect this is a bug of .NET Framework. Because in .NET Core 3.1, `b.IndexOf(" ")` doesn't return -1... Neither does `b.IndexOf(' ', StringComparison.CurrentCulture)`.** Other languages/platforms where "maɪ ˈprɛznt" contains a space culture-sensitively include:

- Mono 6
- Swift 5

Passing in `StringComparison.Ordinal` works:

```
b.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

But do note that you lose the smartness of culture-sensitive comparison.